# How to setup Kubernetes for a parallel job working on a collection of files

Tags: parallel-processing, kubernetes, jobs, volume, persistent

So I'm basically looking for anyone that can point me in the right direction for setting up Kubernetes to perform a common computation on many work items where each work item is a separate file.

I have been reading the documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/), and it seems to suggest that it is possible, the examples are shown with queues of words and simply printing the words, however, I am having trouble with persistent volumes.

What I need to end up with is a deployment that will take a large file containing data points and split it into several files. **I then want to have a Job object execute several pods, one on each file, performing the computation before passing the files back to the deployment for post-processing.**

I am having trouble finding out how to go about transferring the files, from what I read it seems that a PersistentVolume cannot be bound to more than one pod at once. **So how do I go about passing a file to a single pod in a Job?**

Any suggestions or general direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you already explored Hadoop or Spark, since they are really designed for a problem like you describe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PersistentVolume cannot be bound to more than one pod at once.

Whether a PV is shared among Nodes/Pods (or not) is determined by the [accessMode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes); it's not the case that all PVs are universally bound to just one Node/Pod

As the chart on that page shows, there are many PV technologies that tolerate `ReadWriteMany`, with the most famous of them being NFS

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using AzureFile and that worked well enough for my needs.